# PHP set_time_limit not working for exec

Tags: php, exec

I have a strange behavior of the time limit mgmt in PHP (v5.4.13).

I set `max_execution_time` to `30` in `php.ini`, in my script I call:

```
set_time_limit(1000) ;
```

and to be sure it is set I call:

```
error_log (ini_get('max_execution_time'));
```

which returns me 1000. But now if I call a program with

```
exec("foobar.exe") ;
```

(A long program, it takes about 5 minutes to run), the script stop with an error in the log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded
```

My problem is why this script stops after 120 seconds? Any ideas?

Comment: try set_time_limit(0)

Comment: Same with set_time_limit(0)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the issue.

That was stupid:
Between my set_time_limit(1000); and my exec("..."); I called few functions. Looking deeper in these functions, what a surprise! a set_time_limit(120);

Thanks everybody for your help!

Comment: Ahahaha, dude, it's really helpful for me too)))

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini to see if Safe_Mode is ON. If so, max_execution_time has no effect.

Comment: There is no safe mode with php 5.4?! http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php

Comment: Ok, are you on a shared hosting?

Comment: No, a dedicated Windows server.

Comment: And Apache? If so, check your Virtual Host file, if the max execution time is set there (on Apache level instead of PHP level), then the setting cannot be overridden. Solution then is to remove it from the Apache settings, and set it in your php settings, which CAN be overridden.

Comment: There is not configuration directive about time limit for PHP in Apache.

Comment: Have you checked all sub-configuration files of Apache? .htaccess files? Are you using any framework that can be overriding these settings? Maybe the settings of a module in Apache?

Comment: Yes! (that's why I take time to answer you...), No framework. The strange think is scripts can run up to the max_execution_time. It's just the exec command who fail after 120 seconds...